# how can i access title,doc_loc from this json array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

DATA_RECEIVED:

```
data:  [{
         "doc_id": 19,
         "title" : "8-2-2.pdf",
         "doc_loc":"D:upload1/content/8-2-2.pdf",
         "size":"3.59MB",
         "created_by":1,
         "created_time":"Last Sync: 15/3/2014 @ 9:31:57"
       }]
```

this is my json array.i have to extract each of the items from this array.I tried data.title,
but it seemes to be undefined.

Comment: try data[0].title, since received data is an array of objects. If it still shows undefined, then check in console typeof data. If its string then parse the data as JSON - JSON.parse(data). Hope it will help

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
console.log(data[0].title)
console.log(data[0].doc_loc)
```